# OLEDB conection se cae al procesar gran cantidad de archivos

Tags: c#, oledb

tengo un problema con oledb en C# resulta que es una consola que lee archivos .xlsx de una carpeta (170 archivos en total) pero cuando va en la lectura N° 120 se cae y el error es "Desconocido"

```
OleDbConnection Econ;
Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
string qTotal = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$]");
string qTotalvalores = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$B12:H755]");
OleDbCommand ETotal = new OleDbCommand(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbCommand Etotal2 = new OleDbCommand(qTotalvalores, Econ);

termino = termino + 1;

Econ.Open(); //al procesar el archivo n° 120 //Se cae la conexion en Econ.Open();

// Creacion de Dataset para cada uno de los contructores
DataSet dsTotal = new DataSet();
DataSet dsTotal2 = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotalvalores, Econ);

Econ.Close();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ha recibido el archivo °120? es posible que tenga un error. Intente buscar `E_FAIL 0x80004005 oledb` en Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaria que el codigo lo definas dentro de un bloque `using` para asegurar que los objetos se destruyen de forma correcta

```
using(OleDbConnection Econ= new OleDbConnection(constr)){
    Econ.Open();

    //resto del codigo
}
```

de esta forma el `garbage collector` se asegura que el objeto se destruye de forma efectiva y no deja conexiones huerfanas

No hace falta definir un Close() de la conexion al final, cuando sales del scope del using los objetos de ese ambito se destruyen